# Scala type constraint precedence in implicit resolution

Tags: scala, implicit, operator-precedence, implicit-parameters

I have these 2 implicits

```
trait A[T] {
  val name: String
}

trait B

object A {
  implicit def product[T <: Product] = new A[T] {
    override val name: String = "product"
  }

  implicit def childOfB[T <: Product with B] = new A[T] {
    override val name: String = "child of B"
  }
}
```

and if I try to find an implicit instance of `A[C]` where `C` is

```
case class C() extends B
```

`childOfB` will be selected.

I know it is logical but why does this happen? I cannot find it documented anywhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Scala Language Specification](https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.12/07-implicits.html) says:

> If there are several eligible arguments which match the implicit
>   parameter's type, a most specific one will be chosen using the rules
>   of static [overloading resolution](https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.12/06-expressions.html#overloading-resolution).

Overloading resolution has a notion of one symbol being *more specific* than other. Precise, general definition of specificity is quite complex (as you can see in the specification linked above) but in your case it boils down to the fact that `childOfB` covers strictly a subset of types covered by `product` and therefore is *more specific*.

Comment: can you also point me the lines related to this "subset" logic. The specification is too complex for my english.

Answer (score 2):

Specification [says](https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.12/07-implicits.html#implicit-parameters)

> If there are several eligible arguments which match the implicit
>   parameter's type, a most specific one will be chosen using the rules
>   of static [overloading resolution](https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.12/06-expressions.html#overloading-resolution).

Answer (score 2):

To extend @ghik's answer, from *Programmming in Scala*,

> To be more precise, one implicit conversion is *more specific* than another if one of the following applies:
>
> - The argument of the former is a subtype of the latter's
> - Both conversions are methods, and the enclosing class of the former extends the enclosing class of the latter

My guess is that "argument" in that quote refers also to type parameters, as is sugggested by

```
object A {
  implicit def A2Z[T <: A] = new Z[T] {println("A")}
  implicit def B2Z[T <: B] = new Z[T] {println("B")}
}

trait A
trait B extends A

trait Z[T]

def aMethod[T <: A](implicit o: Z[T]) = ()

implicit val a: A = new A {}

aMethod // prints B even though we started with an A
```